# How to apply a conditional to forEach loop in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, data-structures, foreach

```
function createDOMNodes( page ) {

    const currentArray = page === 'result' ?
        resultsArray :
        Object.values( favorites );

    // console.log( 'currentArray' , page , currentArray );
    
    currentArray.latest_photos.forEach( (result) => { // do something } );
}
```

The problem is that there is no `latest_photos` in the `favorites` object, I just want to loop the `currentArray.forEach` when the page parameter is 'favorites'

how can I do that?

It want to switch between different properties when the page is changed. It works fine when I remove the `latest_photos` property.

Is there a way to  Loop through a different array when the page is changed

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `.forEach` instead of `for( of )` ?

Comment: What is `resultsArray`, exactly?

Comment: not at all , I just want to figure out the logic first .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the conditional, take the `latest_photos` instead of the entire `resultsArray`

```
const currentArray = page === 'result'
  ? resultsArray.latest_photos
  : Object.values(favorites);

currentArray.forEach((result) => { // do something }
```

Comment: but this affects my fetch statement, it only returns only 4 photos , for some reason , instead of 10  . is there a reason for that?

Comment: There is no fetch in your question..? What code are you referring to? That sounds like a completely separate issue

Comment: hey sorry to bother you ! I think there is a issue with the api .